# Using I2C: Master Reader and Writer

Tags: algorithm, hardware, i2c, arduino-uno

I'm using I2C and the Arduino Library (Wire) to communicate between two Arduinos, and my code isn't working. It's supposed to read in an int from the slave, write a value to the slave, then read back that value. I'm expecting "0 4", but i keep getting "0 0". Does this mean that the slave isn't registering the write?

Master code:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin();        
  Serial.begin(9600);  
  ffsis();
}

void ffsis()
{ 
  //request i
  Wire.requestFrom(2, 1);   
  int i = Wire.read(); 
  Serial.print(i); 

  //send n seed
  Wire.beginTransmission(2); 
  Wire.write(12);               
  Wire.endTransmission();   

  Serial.print(" ");

  //request n
  Wire.requestFrom(2, 1); 
  int n = Wire.read();
  Serial.print(n);
}

void loop()
{
  delay(100);
}
```

Slave code:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(2);                
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvents);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvents);
}

void loop(){}

int n = 0;

void requestEvents()
{
  Wire.write(n);
}

void receiveEvents(int howMany)
{  
  int n = wire.read();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> int n = wire.read();

"Wire" should be capitalized.

Amplifying on Ken's reply, you have two variables called "n", **and** the global one should be declared **volatile**. Also, I<sup>2</sup>C deals in bytes, not ints, so preferably do this:

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(2);                
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvents);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvents);
}

void loop(){}

volatile byte n = 0;

void requestEvents()
{
  Wire.write(n);
}

void receiveEvents(int howMany)
{  
  n = Wire.read();
}
```

In addition, the address 2 is a *reserved address*.

> Address 0 is reserved as a "broadcast" address, addresses 1 to 7 are reserved for other purposes, and addresses 120 to 127 are reserved for future use.

You should choose an address in the range 8 to 119.

#### Reference

- [I2C - Two-Wire Peripheral Interface - for Arduino](http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c)
- [Official I2C specification](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 
int n
in the receiveEvents function, you're making a new local variable, not using the global n variable.

Comment: Your answer is correct but it could be made better if you provided further explanations on variable scopes in C/C++, and maybe post the updated code.